# If statement inside requestanimationframe continues even if parameters aren't met

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little video game, where the background (platform) moves down with my character (square) jumps. On line 113 I have tried different strategies to implement this thought, and that is the closest it has gotten to work. The issue is that even when the square velocity is 0, the platform velocity isn't. I have been stuck for a week now, and feels like javascript is the problem (even though I know it isn't).

```
canvasmain.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvasmain.height = window.innerHeight;

//CHARACTER:
const square = {
    height: 75,
    jumping: true,
    width: 75,
    x: canvasmain.width / 2,
    xVelocity: 0,
    y: canvasmain.height / 2,
    yVelocity: 0
  };

  //floor
  const platform = {
      height: 30,
      width: 100,
      x: square.x,
      xVelocity: 0,
      y: square.y + square.height,
      yVelocity:0
  }

//MOVEMENT:
const controller = {
    left: false,
    right: false,
    up: false,
    keyListener: function (event) {
      let key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left arrow
          controller.left = key_state;
          break;
        case 38: // up arrow
          controller.up = key_state;
          break;
        case 39: // right arrow
          controller.right = key_state;
          break;
      }
    }
  };
  const loop = function () {

    if (controller.up && square.jumping == false) {
      square.yVelocity -= 30;
      square.jumping = true;
    }
  
    if (controller.left) {
      square.xVelocity -= 0.5;
    }
  
    if (controller.right) {
      square.xVelocity += 0.5;
    }
  
    square.yVelocity += 1.5;// gravity
    square.x += square.xVelocity;
    square.y += square.yVelocity;
    square.xVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
    square.yVelocity *= 0.9;// friction

    // if square is falling below floor line
    if (square.y > canvasmain.height - 75) {
  
      square.jumping = false;
      square.y = canvasmain.height - 75;
      square.yVelocity = 0;
  
    }
  
    // if square is going off the left of the screen
    if (square.x < 0) {
  
      square.x = 0;
  
    } else if (square.x > canvasmain.width - 75) {// if square goes past right boundary
  
      square.x = canvasmain.width - 75;
  
    }
    // Creates the backdrop for each frame
    context.fillStyle = "#394129";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasmain.width, canvasmain.height); // x, y, width, height
  

    // Creates and fills the cube for each frame
    context.fillStyle = "#8DAA9D"; // hex for cube color
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
    context.fill();
  

    // Creates the "ground" for each frame
    context.fillStyle = "#202020";
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(platform.x, platform.y, platform.width, platform.height)
    context.fill();

    // call update when the browser is ready to draw again
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

    //platform
    platform.y += platform.yVelocity;

    console.log(square.yVelocity)
  
    if (square.yVelocity > 0.1 ) {
      platform.yVelocity = 1.5
  };
    
    if (square.yVelocity < 0 ) {
      platform.yVelocity = -1.5
  };
}

  window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
  window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Comment: You've set `platform.yVelocity` to `1.5` or `-1.5`, but never assign `0` to the property.

Comment: it's not quite clear what you've trying to achieve

Comment: @Teemu in the first part I have it set: const platform = {
      height: 30,
      width: 100,
      x: square.x,
      xVelocity: 0,
      y: square.y + square.height,
      yVelocity:0
  }

Comment: @B_Joker I'm trying to get the platform to move downward when the square's y moves upward.

Comment: Yes, but when `.yVelocity` changes during the animation, you're not resetting the value. Maybe you should add an `if` to check `square.yVelocity == 0`, and if that passes, set `.yVelocity` to zero ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reseting the value of `yVelocity`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it guys, thx @Teemu, I just needed to set it to 0 if it wasn't the if's. Dang, really took a while. `if (square.yVelocity > 0 ) {platform.yVelocity = 1.5} else{ platform.yVelocity = 0}; if (square.yVelocity < 0 ) {platform.yVelocity = -1.5} else { platform.yVelocity = 0} }` 
edit: frick, it only moves the platform when the cube is going up, not down ;-;

Comment: just needed to add an else { platform.yVelocity = 0}